# SQL WHERE IN () Performance Optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, performance, database-performance

I checked several questions for a duplicate but I couldn't find one. I am dealing with three tables, the first "articles", the second "tags", and the third "article_tags" which contains two foreign keys "articleid" and "tagid". The table "article_tags" relates articles sharing the same tag together.

My SQL query is as follows:

```
'Getting 4 tag ids from table article_tags
MyCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT TOP (4) at.tagid FROM articles a, article_tags at WHERE at.articleid=a.id AND at.articleid=@id", myconnection)
MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = intID
Dim daQuery = New SqlDataAdapter(MyCommand)
Dim dtArticleTags = New DataTable
daQuery.Fill(dtArticleTags)
Dim strTagIds As String = ""
If dtArticleTags.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    'Save all tags id's in a string "strTags"
    '--------------------------------------------- 
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each myrow As DataRow In dtArticleTags.Rows
        'Store the Tag Ids in a string
        strTagIds += myrow.Item("tagid").ToString
        If i <> dtArticleTags.Rows.Count - 1 Then
            strTagIds += ","
        End If
        i += 1
    Next
    '--------------------------------------------- 
    'Getting 5 related articles sharing the same tags (Note: I know that strTagIds is not parametrized but this can never be inputted by a user)
    MyCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT TOP(5) at.articleid FROM article_tags at, articles a WHERE a.id=at.articleid AND a.publish_flag=1 AND SYSDATETIME() > DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), SYSDATETIME()), a.publish_date) AND at.tagid IN (" & strTagIds & ") AND at.articleid<>@id Group by at.articleid, a.publish_date ORDER BY a.publish_date DESC", myconnection)
    MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = intID
    daRelated = New SqlDataAdapter(MyCommand)
    daRelated.Fill(dsArticle, "related")
End If
```

I feel that the above query is taking time to load especially with the "article_tags" table growing bigger. I am using SQL Express Edition and the tables are indexed and I would like to know if this can be done in a better way to enhance performance.

Attached is the Execution Plan:

[image]

Running the below query as suggested by @SuperPoney, returned the same results, and below is the execution plan:

```
WITH top_art AS
(
    SELECT TOP (4) at.tagid
    FROM articles a, article_tags at
    WHERE at.articleid=a.id
    AND at.articleid=@id
)
SELECT TOP(5) at.articleid
FROM article_tags at, articles a, top_art
WHERE a.id=at.articleid
AND a.publish_flag=1
AND SYSDATETIME() > DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), SYSDATETIME()), a.publish_date)
AND at.tagid=top_art.tag_id
AND at.articleid<>@id
Group by at.articleid, a.publish_date
ORDER BY a.publish_date DESC
```

[image]

Comment: Re "I feel that..." - run your query in SSMS, record its execution plan, show it (there is some site where you can paste it) and then we can say something meaningful :)

Comment: Query performance is affected by indexes, statistics and the execution plan. The query optimizer is smart enough to simplify queries and generate the *same* execution plan for queries with different syntax but identical logical behavior.

Comment: What is this clause trying to achieve - `SYSDATETIME() > DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), SYSDATETIME()), a.publish_date)`?

Comment: What is the actual result you're looking for? Seems to me like you're attempting to do the join in code instead of using sql properly.

Comment: Execution plan added to the question.
Making sure that the date on the server is bigger than publish_date.
Trying to retrieve the latest articles sharing the same tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get everything you need in a single query:

```
SELECT  TOP (5) a.ID
FROM    article AS a
WHERE   a.publish_flag = 1 
AND     a.publish_date <  DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), SYSDATETIME()), SYSDATETIME())
AND     a.Id <> @ID 
AND     EXISTS 
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    article_tags AS at
            WHERE   at.ArticleID = a.ID
            AND     EXISTS  
                    (   SELECT  1 
                        FROM    article_tags AS at2
                        WHERE   at2.ArticleID = @ID
                        AND     at2.TagID = at.TagID
                    )
        )
ORDER BY a.publish_date DESC;
```

I have assumed that you were originally using `TOP 4` for tags as an arbitrary limit for performance reasons, as there was no sort. So have ommitted this. I have also changed your predicate from:

```
SYSDATETIME() > DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), SYSDATETIME()), a.publish_date)
```

to

```
a.publish_date <  DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), SYSDATETIME()), SYSDATETIME())
```

The meaning is the same, however by calling the `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` functions on the run time constants `SYSDATETIME()` and `UTCDATETIME()` it means this calculation is only done once, rather than once for every `a.publish_date` meaning any index on `publish_date` is now usable.

The other change I have made is to use `EXISTS` rather than `JOIN` to link articles to tags. This will avoid duplicates, however it would be equally trivial to remove duplicates using `GROUP BY` e.g.

```
SELECT  TOP (5) a.ID
FROM    article AS a
        INNER JOIN article_tags AS at
            ON at.ArticleID = a.ID
WHERE   a.publish_flag = 1 
AND     a.publish_date <  DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), SYSDATETIME()), SYSDATETIME())
AND     a.Id <> @ID 
AND     EXISTS  
        (   SELECT  1 
            FROM    article_tags AS at2
            WHERE   at2.ArticleID = @ID
            AND     at2.TagID = at.TagID
        )
GROUP BY a.ID, a.publish_date
ORDER BY a.publish_date DESC;
```

A few side notes as well that don't directly relate to the above answer, but are still worth mentioning.

1. The Implicit join syntax you are using was replaced 28 years ago by ANSI 92 explicit join syntax. There [are plenty of good reasons](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) to switch to the "new" syntax, so I would advise you do.
2. Parameterised queries are about more than just SQL Injection attacks (including but not limited to type safety and query plan caching), so just because your input isn't coming from a user doesn't mean you shouldn't use parametrized queries.
3. I would strongly advise against re-using your SqlClient objects (SqlConnection, SqlCommand), create a new object for each use, and dispose of it correctly when done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So how can tell if the query performs better? Just by running the execution plan? Regarding SqlClient objects, they are placed inside a USING statement which should dispose of automatically. Thanks for the support.

Comment: I think this is a good answer (and have upvoted it as such). The big advantage of this query is that it can use indexes for seeks, rather than full table/index scans. For scale, you will need to ensure you have indexes appropriate e.g., at least publish_date in articles table, and articleid in article_tags. Then SQL server can just jump right to the relevant spots in the table.

Comment: The reason I used TOP(4) is that each article can have a maximum of 4 tags.

Comment: The execution plan will give you some idea of performance, but there is no substitute for simply benchmarking. If you want to compare two queries, run them both, multiple times with different parameters and see which one consistently performs better.

Comment: @GarethD the mistake that was done is that I used two queries and some code to achieve what I needed while it can be achieved in a single query. Also, the query I used was checking SYSDATETIME() on all articles rather than just checking publish_date once, correct?

Answer (score 1):

My first advice is "let the database do is job".
Can you parse the Query Plan of these two queries in you database?

Maybe this will answer your question.

Query #1

```sql
SELECT TOP(5) at.articleid
FROM article_tags at, articles a
WHERE a.id=at.articleid
AND a.publish_flag=1
AND SYSDATETIME() > DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), SYSDATETIME()), a.publish_date)
AND at.tagid IN (
    SELECT TOP (4) at.tagid
    FROM articles a, article_tags at
    WHERE at.articleid=a.id
    AND at.articleid=@id
)
AND at.articleid<>@id
Group by at.articleid, a.publish_date
ORDER BY a.publish_date DESC
```

Query #2

```sql
WITH top_art AS
(
    SELECT TOP (4) at.tagid
    FROM articles a, article_tags at
    WHERE at.articleid=a.id
    AND at.articleid=@id
)
SELECT TOP(5) at.articleid
FROM article_tags at, articles a, top_art
WHERE a.id=at.articleid
AND a.publish_flag=1
AND SYSDATETIME() > DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), SYSDATETIME()), a.publish_date)
AND at.tagid=top_art.tagid
AND at.articleid<>@id
Group by at.articleid, a.publish_date
ORDER BY a.publish_date DESC
```

Comment: I think you should fix the top_art.tag_id to be top_art.tagid. I executed the query and it returned the same results. I'll add the execution plan to the question.

Comment: I've fixed the typo :)